# Automatically adding headers to Rebus messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rebus

When configuring the Rebus bus, you can specify that it should look for the `Headers.UserName` header as described [here](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/User-context). This allows you to automatically populate the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with the proper username. This works great, but I wonder if there is a good way to set the header in a standard way instead of manually setting it when sending each message.

I'm building an ASP.NET Web API based service and would like each request to set the header to be the name found in `apiControllerInstance.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name`.

A decent solution would be to create a method on a base `ApiController` which has access to the message bus, so you can do something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction(SomeMessage message)
{
    SendWithUser(message);
    return Ok();
}
```

The problem is that you have to remember to do this, so I would like to get some suggestions on how to do this in a more general fashion. Also, other headers might become relevant in the future which would also be problematic with this approach.

### Update

Based on mookid's answer, I came up with the following solution (I have just verified that it works for one of my requests but I make no promises regarding robustness):

```
public static void SetUserNameHeaderWhenCurrentPrincipalIsPresent(this IRebusEvents events)
{
    events.MessageSent += (bus, destination, message) =>
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            bus.AttachHeader(message, Headers.UserName, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
.Events(e => e.SetUserNameHeaderWhenCurrentPrincipalIsPresent())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Events(e => e.MessageSent += SetUsername)
```

to have `SetUsername` called for each outgoing message, and that's where you can do a lookup on `HttpContext.Current`

Please let me know how that works out for youor if you think something else is missing :)

Comment: there is no Events configuration method in the newer version of Rebus, how to add custom eventhandlers to the events in newer versions of Rebus?

Comment: Is it possible to convert the "HttpContext.Current" to "HttpRequestMessage" with autofac ? 
I need to support self-hosting environment.

Comment: there's a [Rebus.Events](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Events) package for the newer versions of Rebus! (sorry about the late answer :))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the decorator pattern combined with autofac. The following example illustrate a possible solution:

```
public class RebusConfig  {

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //Autofac configuration to decorate Rebus
        builder.RegisterDecorator<IBus>(
                    (c, inner) => new RebusMetadataDecorator(
                            inner, c.Resolve<HttpRequestMessage>()),
                    fromKey: "Metadata")
                     .InstancePerRequest();

    }

    public override SetContainer(IContainer container){
            //Configure the desired rebus
            var bus = Rebus.Config.Configure.With(new AutofacContainerAdapter(container));

            //Reconfigure rebus to support decorator
            //Note: I want to improve this step!
            var containerUpdate = new ContainerBuilder();

            containerUpdate
                  .RegisterInstance(bus)
                  .SingleInstance()
                  .Named<IBus>("Metadata");

            containerUpdate.Update(container);
     }          
}           

//Rebus Decorator               
public class RebusMetadataDecorator : IBus
{
        private  HttpRequestMessage requestMessage;
        private  IBus bus;

        public RebusMetadataDecorator(
            IBus bus, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
        {
            this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
            this.bus = bus;
        }

        public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent message)
        {
            SetHttpMetadataToHeader(bus, message, metadataProvider, prefix);
            bus.Publish<TEvent>(message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The header can be added to the send message in a nice way. Example below.

```
private readonly IBus messageBus;
...
var expirationHeader = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { Headers.TimeToBeReceived, "00:00:30" },
};

this.messageBus.Send(reqMsg, expirationHeader).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Can you provide a written explanation to supplement the code you have provided?